# variable date option in opencart

Tags: opencart

1st I want to remove text field for date so the calendar will replace it.

2nd I want to make the status order.. I want to sell the service, so I need to make booking order by calendar. If the date is green client can make an order. If red the client can't book an order. If yellow there certain items can be ordered.

[image]

I hope someone can help..

Thanks.

Comment: Please consider providing some detail on [What You Have Tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

You have to try something at least and ask only for advice then.

Anyway, few suggestions:

1. it cannot be done using that option field of type date, at least not with the default datepicker.
2. You will need to create Your own datepicker component that will search for free/partialy/fully ordered days in the database and color the table cells accordingly.
3. It is not very wise to hide the input - by this visible user could anytime check what date did he pick - if it is not visible he would need to always open the datepicker to check for it...
4. Disallowing to order some service based on some reservations is highly decreasing Your conversion rate - thus decreasing Your income. I would definitely go the way let the user buy/order anything at anytime while having separate reservation system. If user buys a service at thank You page I would recommend him to book a concrete date for the service to be drawn. Here You do not need to fight with product options which are meant totally for something different that You are trying to.

Keep that in mind (mainly the 4<sup>th</sup> point) and re-think Your problem.